# Editor not supporting scrolling inside the listview for UWP Xamarin

Tags: windows, xamarin, uwp, uwp-xaml

**Editor inside ListView which not supporting Scrolling**

scrolling is supporting in both android and ios but i am geting problem with UWP

```
 <ListView 
         x:Name="listProjects" 
         HasUnevenRows="true"
         SeparatorVisibility="None"
         ItemsSource="{Binding Feedbacks}"
         HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
         ItemTapped="Handle_ItemTapped">

        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
             <ViewCell>
            <StackLayout  Padding="15,15,15,15" BackgroundColor="Transparent">
               <Editor HeightRequest="50" FontSize="Small"/>
                </StackLayout>
             </ViewCell>
          </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
 </ListView>
```

Answer (score 0):

> scrolling is supporting in both android and ios but i am geting problem with UWP

Yes, currently the Editor control is not scrollable as child of ViewVell in UWP app, I've seen you created a bug in **bugzilla** site: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=43660

The workaround here is to customize a `ViewCell` and create the custom renderer on each Platform. For UWP, use [`RichEditBox`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.richeditbox.aspx) control or other scrollable control as an alternative.

Please see the document: [Customizing a ViewCell](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/custom-renderer/viewcell/)

**XAML:**

```
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
  <DataTemplate>
    <local:NativeCell Name="{Binding Name}" Category="{Binding Category}" />
  </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

**NativeCell:**

```
public class NativeCell : ViewCell
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty NameProperty =
      BindableProperty.Create("Name", typeof(string), typeof(NativeCell), "");

    public string Name
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(NameProperty); }
        set { SetValue(NameProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty CategoryProperty =
      BindableProperty.Create("Category", typeof(string), typeof(NativeCell), "");

    public string Category
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(CategoryProperty); }
        set { SetValue(CategoryProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

**Customized render for UWP:**

```
using WorkingWithListview;
using WorkingWithListview.UWP.Renderers;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UWP;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(NativeCell), typeof(NativeUWPCellRenderer))]
namespace WorkingWithListview.UWP.Renderers
{
    public class NativeUWPCellRenderer : ViewCellRenderer
    {
        public override Windows.UI.Xaml.DataTemplate GetTemplate(Cell cell)
        {
            return App.Current.Resources["ListViewItemTemplate"] as Windows.UI.Xaml.DataTemplate;
        }
    }
}
```

**The data template in App.xaml:**

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="ListViewItemTemplate">
        <Grid Background="LightBlue">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="100" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="0.40*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="0.40*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="0.20*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <RichEditBox Grid.Row="1" />
            <TextBlock Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Foreground="#7F3300" FontStyle="Italic" FontSize="22" VerticalAlignment="Top" Text="{Binding Name}" />
            <Line Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" X1="0" X2="1" Margin="30,20,0,0" StrokeThickness="1" Stroke="LightGray" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
```

**Screenshot:**
[image]

**Check my completed sample [here](https://github.com/Myfreedom614/UWP-Samples/tree/master/WorkingWithListview)**

Comment: Thanks, Franklin, its working,but here i also need to set binding context to  editor but RichEditBox is not supprting Text property.

Comment: @SachinKs Good to know, so is this the acceptable answer for your question? ;)

Comment: yes it is acceptable but here i also need to set binding context to Text property to set default text in RichEditBox, is there any way to do this?

Comment: @SachinKs sure, but this question is not related to the original one, based on stackoverflow rule, please ask a new question, I will give you suggestions there:) (You can tell me the link here)